# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')

Tags: reactjs

The problem I'm having is that it's not redirecting me to the screen specified on line 54 `this.props.history.push('/');` because the following message appears in the console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')
    at Login.js:54:1
```

```
import { Avatar, Container, Typography, Button, TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import LockOutlineIcon from "@material-ui/icons/LockOutlined";
import { compose } from 'recompose';
import { consumerFirebase } from '../../server';

const style={
    paper: {
        marginTop: 9,
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        alignItems: "center"
    },
    avatar: {
        margin: 5,
        backgroundColor: "red"
    },
    form : {
        width : "100%",
        marginTop : 8
    }
    
}

class Login extends Component {
    state = {
        firebase : null,
        usuario : {
            email : '',
            password : ''
        }
    }
    static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState){
        if(nextProps.firebase === prevState.firebase){
            return null;
        }
        return {
            firebase : nextProps.firebase
        }
    }
    onChange = e => {
        let usuario = Object.assign({}, this.state.usuario);
        usuario[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
        this.setState({
            usuario : usuario
        })
    }
    login = e =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        const { firebase, usuario } = this.state;
        firebase.auth
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(usuario.email, usuario.password)
        .then( auth => {
            this.props.history.push('/');
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
                <Container maxWidth="xs" >
                <div style={style.paper} >
                    <Avatar style={style.avatar} >
                        <LockOutlineIcon />
                    </Avatar>
                    <Typography component="h1" variant="h5" >
                        Ingrese usuario
                    </Typography>
                    <form style={style.form} >
                        <TextField
                            variant="outlined"
                            label="E-Mail"
                            name="email"
                            fullWidth
                            margin="normal"
                            onChange={this.onChange}
                            value = {this.state.usuario.email}
                        />
                        <TextField
                            variant="outlined"
                            label="Password"
                            type="password"
                            name="password"
                            fullWidth
                            margin="normal"
                            onChange={this.onChange}
                            value = {this.state.usuario.password}
                        />
                        <Button
                            type='submit'
                            fullWidth
                            variant='contained'
                            color="primary"
                            onClick={this.login}
                        >
                            Enviar
                        </Button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                </Container>
        );
    }
}

export default compose(consumerFirebase) (Login);
```

Comment: Do you have a route for `/` in your app?

Comment: You can only use `this.props.history.push()` function inside the component page that is already listed on your project route, or simply use the `withRouter()` HOC if the component is not available in the route list.

Comment: `export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(ChildView));`